# addEventListener isn't updated after property change

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ecmascript-6

i need to show an Alertbox after all checkboxes are unchecked. If User clicks on "Cancel" the last active Checkbox should be "checked" again.

After Alertbox has been closed the active Checkbox will be set to "checked" by

```
actionOnClose[1].checked = true;
```

So why "change" Listener doesn't get updated by this line

```
actionOnClose[1].checked = true;
```

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.orders-checkbox'),
    checkboxArray = Array.from(checkboxes),
    checkboxesAll = checkboxArray.length,
    checkboxCounter = 0,
    cancleOrderUrl = document.querySelector('input.confirm-cancel');

let alertBox = (data, routeTo, $form = null, ...actionOnClose) =>
{
    Swal.fire({
        // config code
        onClose: () => {
            switch (actionOnClose[0]) {
                case 'restoreCheckbox':
                    actionOnClose[1].checked = true;
                    // resetting counter to 2 does not work
                    // checkboxCounter = 2;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
};

let observeCheckbox = (event) =>
{
    let self = event.target;

    if (!self.checked) {
        checkboxCounter++;
    }

    if (self.checked) {
        checkboxCounter--;
    }

    if (checkboxCounter === checkboxesAll) {
        alertBox('orders_cancel', cancleOrderUrl.getAttribute('data-route'), null, 'restoreCheckbox', self);
    }
};

checkboxArray.forEach(function (checkbox)
{
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', event => observeCheckbox(event), true);
});
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="line_items[]" id="7858" value="7858" class="orders-checkbox" checked="checked">

<input type="checkbox" name="line_items[]" id="7859" value="7859" class="orders-checkbox" checked="checked">

<input type="checkbox" name="line_items[]" id="7860" value="7860" class="orders-checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Changing the `checked` property value of a checkbox directly in the code does not trigger the event. It's a bit confusing, but it's just how it works.

Comment: A UI tweak that I used to get around this issue in a work app was simply to disable the checkbox if it was the last one with a check. What's nice about that is you don't need an alert anymore and the user can no longer ever do the illegal operation (unchecking the last box).

Comment: @EdLucas I can't just disable that last checkbox. If all items in an order are deselected then the alert box will be used to display an option to cancel the entire order. If the seller clicks on Cancel, then the last deactivated item should be reactivated

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with local / global vars i have found a working Solution

define counter as global var

```
window.checkboxCounter = 0;
```

now it is possible to reset counter

```
switch (actionOnClose[0]) {
   case 'restoreCheckbox':
      // check last unchecked checkbox
      actionOnClose[1].checked = true;

      // reset counter
      window.checkboxCounter = checkboxesAll - 1;
      break;

      default:
         break;
}
```